# Hover effect on a background pattern repeated

Tags: html, css

I have a pattern image with the background-repeat attribute set, so the image is reapeated in X and Y axis in a div.

Now I want to change the background image when the user go over the div.

It would be simple with a fullsize background, because I will transform it in a sprite and then move the background with css and :hover .

But if the image is repeated X and Y, is it impossibile to create a sprite; right? 
Or there is any sort of trick to do this? 
Because changing directly the image via css is bad to see, because the hover image need to be loaded and there is like 1-2 sec that the user doesn't see any background in the div.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle or something with what you have so far?

Comment: Have you tried with two div with same dimension but different background and z-index?

Comment: @squaleLis I cannot use two div, because there is content in this div and I don't want to have two elements with the same content, it is a wast of bandwidth loading two time the same thing

Comment: @GOB No sorry, I don't have any js fiddle

Comment: @Cappec and if you play with :before/:after? so you set them with your backgrounds, and change their z-index on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [preload image](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/) 
OR 
Use two nested elements with two different backgrounds.
On mouseover - make transparent background  for nested element.

Comment: Perfect! Is what I was looking for, the Technique #2 (put the hover background in another element positioned -9999px -9999px so the browser will load it) is a good trick :)
Thanks!